# Почему возникает ошибка object is not callable?

Tags: python-3.x

При повторном вызове функции och, выдаёт ошибку:

```
    self.och()
    TypeError: 'Myoch' object is not callable
```

вот часть кода:

```
    def opr(self):
    path = File_location + "1_classes/" + self.lineEdit1.text() + '.txt'
    try:
        file = open(path)
    except IOError as e:
        self.och()
    else:
        self.uch()
```

функция och:

```
    def och(self):
        self.och = Myoch()
        self.och.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если называть функцию och, а потом в функцию давать переменной имя och, то чего же другого ожидать? Переименуй или функцию или переменную и никогда так больше не делай!